# How location tracking is different than other background task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parallel-processing, geolocation

In Windows Phone 8, it is suggested that, if I use LocationTracking as suggested in following code, my application will get location information *continuously*.

```
<BackgroundExecution>
<ExecutionType Name=”LocationTracking” />
</BackgroundExecution>
```

Now, Background Agent only executed after ~30 mins, and which is also with lots of limitations, like, it may run or may not run depending on OS.

How `LocationTracking` is different than *Background Agent*. Will it gives location every time location changes, or still it may invoke after 30 min.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> On Windows Phone 8, a location-tracking app can continue to run in the background after the user navigates away, as long as the app continues to actively track location. This feature enables scenarios such as an app that provides turn-by-turn directions. For a walkthrough of creating a simple app that runs in the background, see How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8.

There are also more differences and you must look out for [API restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You can compare it with [Background agent unsupported api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

And you should also be aware of some [Additional requirements for specific app types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: So, can we say, location tracking is *exception* to normal `BackgrounAgent` limitations in WP8?

Comment: @pranitkothari yes it is. And you must also be aware of certification requirements concerned with that. I heard about some apps faking location tracking, but I do not now if they passed certification.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Unfortunately I don't know the answer right away.

Comment: @Romasz Ok No problem. I want to track user's location and based on a parameter send it to server when the app is in background. Can you able to suggest how I can achieve it ?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar As you have asked about WP8.0, then take a look a [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681691(v=vs.105).aspx) and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: @Romasz Yes, this are fine but can you suggest how I can send data to the server in the background. I found that there are lots of limitations using Background Agents.